# Router for a portion of a page

Tags: ember-router

Does the view <--> URL matching pairs, effectively mean that the router has to control the entire page and cannot be used for controlling a subset of the page?  I have a situation where Ember is used for a portion of a page where the outermost container view is manually added to a DOM element.  A workaround would be to convert the entire page to Ember but perhaps there are other ways?  Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `outlets` to insert a dynamic portion of a page. An outlet renders the current view. In that view there can be another outlet to display the subview.

See this example:

**application template**

```
<div id="content">
  <nav> .. menu part .. </nav>
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

This renders the dynamic part of your app. When you browse to for instance `/pages` you can display a list of pages in it. When you go to '/pages/1' there is an `{{outlet}}` in the `pages`-template which renders the `page`-template.

**pages template**

```
<ul>
{{#each page in controller}}
  <li>{{#linkTo page}}{{page.name}}{{/linkTo}}</li> 
{{/each}}
</ul>
{{outlet}}
```

**page template**

```
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
```

The page-name header is now rendered below the pages-list.
This way you can add as much dynamic content as you want.